# How to implement Oplock (opportunistic locking) in .NET?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, winapi, io, filesystems

I need to implement Oplock ([opportunistic locking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/oplock-overview)) in .NET project. Here is the scenario that I need to implement:

1. App 1 opens the file and does NOT allow writing (for example, opens a file with `FileShare.Read`).
2. App 2 requests writing to the file (opens a file with `FileAccess.Write`).
3. App 1 receives a notification that the writing is requested. It confirms breaking the lock and allows App 2 to write to the file.

There is a full asynchronous I/O support in the `FileStream` class and there is also [`NativeOverlapped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.nativeoverlapped?view=net-5.0) structure in .NET. Looks like .NET has everything needed for Oplock. However there is no any  example how to use `NativeOverlapped` and [`NativeOverlapped.EventHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.nativeoverlapped.eventhandle?view=net-5.0) field required to handle the oplock break and no any parameters for this structure.

Is Oplock is supported in .NET at all? Are there any Oplock example?

Comment: but this is already implemeented by windows. you simply do `FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK` in App1 with `OPLOCK_LEVEL_CACHE_READ` and `REQUEST_OPLOCK_INPUT_FLAG_REQUEST` and got status pending for this. when App2 writing to the file the `FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK` will be completed

Comment: @Charlieface - you mistake. winapi full support this ( `FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK`) not need any loops

Comment: The .NET Framework has `ReaderWriterLock` and `ReaderWriterLockSlim` that implement the concept of multiple readers-one writer for a lock. This is not file-access specific but of course can be used to control access to a file.

Comment: @PMF that is only per process and nothing common with file oplock

Comment: @RbMm True, I didn't see that this was really about file access. I thought the OP was asking primarily about the _concept_.

Comment: @PMF - i think here main concept that App 2 have no knowledge about App 1 and not use any common synchronization with it